# 0x API showing a different price than what is shown on matcha.xyz

Tags: 0x, price, sushiswap

When I run the below it shows a price that is different from what I see on matcha. Trying to figure out how the price on matcha is derived.

https://api.0x.org/swap/v1/quote?buyToken=ETH&sellToken=0x641927E970222B10b2E8CDBC96b1B4F427316f16&sellAmount=100000000000000000

The above currently shows the below.
"price":"4.98692708386994233"
"guaranteedPrice":"4.9370578130312429"
"estimatedPriceImpact":"0.8238"
"sellTokenToEthRate":"0.19887241352439467"
"buyTokenToEthRate":"1"

Matcha is showing the below.
MEEB/ETH of 5.011426 spot price
and if you set it up to sell 1 MEEB for ETH it shows the price as 4.90376
1 MEEB = 4.90376
1 ETH = 0.203925 MEEB

Can someone please help me understand what I am missing from the output of the 0x API to be able to land at what is being shown on Matcha?

Thanks!

Please let me know if any additional information would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like in this case Matcha might be using [RFQ](https://docs.0x.org/market-makers/docs/introduction) to provide that quote, and RFQ liquidity is only surfaced to integrators with a key.